# My Honda Accord shuts off while on driving

Tags: honda, fuel-system, accord

Just yesterday i decided to get fuel from a place i usually don't , after driving for some hours my car just shout off , i tried accelerating but i couldn't so i parked .

After some minutes i tried starting the car and it was up again , same thing happened today , could this be because of bad fuel , and if it is what are the necessary steps to stop this malfunction

My car is a Honda Accord 2005

Comment: I bet it's water in the fuel, which really sucks with ethanol laced gasoline. You can put some fuel treatment in there which will take care of some water, but you may have more in there than your car can handle. I have no *real* advice for you so am leaving this as a comment. Oh, and once you find a gas station you like, continue to use it and you shouldn't have this problem again. Look for busy gas stations as they turn over their storage very quickly and don't usually have this issue.

Comment: You may want to keep the tank topped up, so that if it is water, it's less likely to suck that through until you've sorted it all out. It would at least buy you some time.

Comment: @Calyth ... the gas will float on the water. Water, being heavier than gas, will be towards the bottom of the tank, which is where the pickup is at. Fuel level will not alter this. If the pump is going to pick it up, it'll do it irregardless.

Comment: @Paulster: So if there were water in  the tank, and it   sinks to the bottom where the pickup is, wouldn't you expect the engine to fail right away, rather than running for "some hours" and then failing? If there is a contaminant in the fuel, it almost sounds more like it's something that floats.

Comment: @Paulster2 That's interesting. I might have to double check my service manual. I was under sa slightly different impression. 

Though at least there's the evap and the charcoal box, so the engine may have started from the vapours while the car's parked.

Comment: @NateEldredge ... It depends on how much is sucked up at any given time. It isn't like it's a lump in the bottom of the tank. It does disperse somewhat. It also doesn't mean it will just hang out at the pickup. If the vehicle is moving, the water will move too. Have no doubt, water ***IS*** heavier than gasoline. The main factor here is *how much* water is in the system. If the pickup grabs a bunch of it at one time, it can cause the engine to die. Realize if water floated on the gas, you'd never have a problem with it unless you ran out of fuel, where water would get picked up last.

Answer (score 2):

The probability of fuel contamination is a possibility, but I would have thought that if it was the case, the vehicle would have shut down and would not have been able to be restarted. I would be inclined to think that you have a failing component. As it is apparently an intermittant fault I would be run the vehicle with a data logger attached to track a re-occurence, after having a vehicle scan.

Comment: I want to add to this answer, as it sit beteween fuel system and other failures. I had this Nissan D-22(Frotier, or Terrano in some countries) that would start without effort run a couple of minutes then it would die. After that toke a lot of engine cranks to start but it'd eventually turn on as always. Changed the 3 fuel filters it had, still the same. Checking the underside I spoted a leak which it came from where the hardline meets the hose, just before the filters. The hose was slit because of fatigue and from above was almost invisible. Spent $ 2 us, for a piece of hose and that was it.

Answer (score 0):

EFI relay, in under hood fuse box on my 2008. Car would not turn over, left key in #2 position and tapped relay, it clicked and fuel pump came to life. Car then started right up.